# Failed to read HTTP message:ion: JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING : Unexpected EOF read on the socket

Tags: rest, spring-boot

When a client is sending an image to one of the rest endpoints, only part of the data is being received.

To be sure what is happening I made a trace with Wireshark and analyzed it. The application is indeed not receiving the last part of the message. This is because the application is not able to receive all the data within the 900ms timeout that is specified on the Client side. Its buffers are full halfway through the reception.

> I get application warning
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver
>   [http-nio-0.0.0.0-9999-exec-35] Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is
>   java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket

And the client gets Connection timeout.

Comment: why not just increase the timeout

Comment: That was the first option I explored but client application has ruled out that. as it is derived from the (peak) throughput of the client application so if it is extended, this will eventually block the checkers.

Comment: I have got a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution to my problem. I have increased the socket buffer size in my application. I have added following code to my Application class.

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.setProtocol("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol");
        tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
            connector.setProperty("socket.rxBufSize", "5000000");
        });
        return tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
    }
```